# Tkinter preserving scroll in Text when updating it

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a Tkinter Text object that is used to display some text. This text rapidly updates for example a line may change from

```
manager.angry=True
```

to

```
manager.angry=False
```

As it is a sort of monitor.

This monitor is monitoring the states of a lot of variables as time goes on so it is a very long log. As such it is necessary to be able to scroll it.

I am currently updating this monitor with the following

```
self.delete(1.0, "end")
self.insert(tk.INSERT, text)
self.update_size(None)
```

Which essentially deletes all the text and replaces it with the new text. In reality there might only be one or two words difference between the two.

The problem is even though the new text usually has the same number of lines the scroll resets when I do this. Making it impossible to actually scroll.

Is there a way to update the text without loosing the users scroll position within the Text object?

Comment: You can use the index `END`. Read up on [The Tkinter Text Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm) and [`see(index)`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#Tkinter.Text.see-method)

Comment: Why delete and re-add text? Why aren't you just adding the new text to the end of the widget?

Comment: @stovfl what would seeing the end of the text do? What if the user had not yet seen the end of the text?

Comment: @BryanOakley I am not adding it to the end as I am updating the values. So for example if a line read that angry=True a few seconds ago that same line may need to read angry=False later on. So it is not new so much as updated.

Comment: @CalebK: I feel you want something like this: [Update scrolled Listbox - wandering scroll position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36086487/7414759)